# Bind IBitmap to ImageView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I try to bind an IBitmap in my ViewModel to an ImageView in an AndroidActivity. The basic bind does not work and asks me to register an `IBindingTypeConverter` for that:

```
class BitmapToImageViewConverter : IBindingTypeConverter
{
    public int GetAffinityForObjects(Type fromType, Type toType)
    {
        return (fromType == typeof (IBitmap) && toType == typeof (ImageView)) ? 2 : 0;
    }

    public bool TryConvert(object from, Type toType, object conversionHint, out object result)
    {
        if (from == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        Drawable drawable = ((IBitmap) from).ToNative();
        ImageView test = new ImageView(WeatherApp.AppContext);
        test.SetImageDrawable(drawable);

        result = test;
        return true;
    }
}
```

That didn't work. So I tried to "convert" it in the OneWayBind like this:`this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.WeatherIcon, v => v.weatherImageView.Drawable, v => v.ToNative());`

But that didn't work either. I'm still new to ReactiveUI so a little hint would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as usual it was the programmer's problem. :D This is the way I did it now and I'm quite happy with the solution. I missed `using System;`, which made C# take the `Subscribe` method from another lib.

```
this.WhenAnyValue(activity => activity.ViewModel.WeatherIcon)
    .Subscribe(image =>
    {
        if (image == null)
            return;

        WeatherImageView.SetImageDrawable(image.ToNative());
    });
```

But I'm still curios if there is a way to solve this problem with a IBindingTypeConverter.